# How to make GitHub's Jekyll work with index.html?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to make a GitHub page. At the beginning, I use GitHub generator. I included `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` to generate SEO tag and it works as expected. The generated site will include the following section.

```
<!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.6.1 -->
  <meta ...
<!-- End Jekyll SEO tag -->
```

Now, I've just updated my site to the new one using HTML template from [HTML5 UP](https://html5up.net/). It's up and run normally, however, I cannot find a way to make Jekyll generate SEO tag for my `index.html` file. I've tried to add triple dashes (front matter) to my `index.html` on the first line.

```
---
---
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Other code below -->
```

The thing is, it partially break the site (page isn't rendered properly). Therefore, I've to copy/paste the generated tag and add them manually to my code. Is there a way to make Jekyll properly create SEO tags for my site? Or did my misunderstand something very basic here?

To be clear, I've very limited knowledge in web development, that's why I use a template in the first place. Here is my page in case it helps clarify the question https://hunghvu.github.io/ and here is its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/hunghvu/hunghvu.github.io) incase you want to know the file structure.

---

**Update**

- (09/30)

  - I attempted to turn the `index.html` file into `index.md` while still keeping all the code (plus the tripled dashes). In a sense, it works. The page is generated, but still, it's not rendered properly as when I use `html` format. I'm aware that the way to actually build site using Jekyll is much different, but that does not answer my question.
  - In case it is necessary to show what I mean by saying "not properly rendered", I will update this question later on.
- (09/31)

  - The picture below is how my page looks like when I add **front matter** and {% seo %}. Notice that when I first go to the page, the side bar is already in `SOME OTHER WORK`, or last section. It should be on the `WELCOME`. The `WELCOME` section is not rendered and sidebar functionality is broken.

[image: Bug 1]

Comment: Did you add the `{% seo %}` tag to your index site?

Comment: I tried, added in the bottom of `head` section but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Whats the result?

Comment: It is rendered as a line of text on the page. Like a pure html page without any css element.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that? I have a suspicion that your default layout might be the reason.

Comment: I just added the screenshot, however, as I also include triple dashes, the behavior is not as I told you. For now, you can just go to my site and see how it display if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

GitHub pages gem is not included in your project, therefore GitHub is not running Jekyll build. Furthermore, you have nothing specified in your front matter. You also have no layout.

## Solution

Include gem `"github-pages", "~> VERSION", group: :jekyll_plugins` in your Gemfile.

## Notes

Consider using front matter and creating a layout file `_layouts/default.html` and moving everything except what’s in body (including SEO)to the layout file. The index.html should extend the layout by specifying layout property in front matter.

## References

Front Matter: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/
GitHub (step 9): https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll

Comment: I will try the `_layouts` approach and report result later. Would you mind elaborate what "**moving everything except what’s in body (including SEO)to the layout file.**" means for me? From what I see, the tutorials you sent (which I actually saw before), are about **fully create GitHub page using Jekyll**, but **what I want is making Jekyll SEO plugin work with my non-Jekyll page** for convenience sake, so I don't think it helps.

Comment: @HungVu You can not. The Jekyll SEO plugin **only** works when you use Jekyll. You can't use it without using Jekyll. You can't have a static page *and* also use the plugin. Thats simply not how this works.

Comment: @Hung Vu start with adding the GitHub gem to your project. Then work through the Jekyll tutorial for creating a layout and etc.

Comment: It appears that there is no way for me to make Jekyll SEO plugins work with the site, unless I rebuild the site completely using Jekyll as suggested, which is not my preferred method. Anyway, thanks for the answer though.